# when i insert data in sql with curly brase it shows input string not correct format error

Tags: c#

```
string query = string.Format(@"if not exists(select id from user_detail where id_str = '" + args.Tweet.CreatedBy.IdStr + "') begin insert into user_detail(id_str,screen_name,user_name,createdate,hashtag,imageurl,message,unique_id,tweet_id)values('" + args.Tweet.CreatedBy.IdStr + "',N'" + args.Tweet.CreatedBy.ScreenName.Replace("'", "`") + "', N'" + args.Tweet.CreatedBy.Name.Replace("'", "`") + "','" + args.Tweet.CreatedAt + "',N'" + Hashtag + "',N'" + Convert.ToString() + "',N'" + args.Tweet.Text.Replace("'", "`") + "','" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "','" + args.Tweet.IdStr + "') end else begin update user_detail set screen_name=N'" + args.Tweet.CreatedBy.ScreenName + "' where id_str = '" + args.Tweet.CreatedBy.IdStr + "' end");
```

Comment: assign the final sql string to local `string sql = ...`, then debug and check the string

Comment: it is really a good idea to use parameterize queries in `SqlCommand` with the `.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ColumnName", "Value");` Otherwise you might be vulnerable to the SQL injection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never concatenate input to create SQL. It will hurt you and hurt you and hurt you. If you use *parameters*, then all issues of escaping will disappear, as will issues relating to culture-info, and the risk of SQL injection. It will also mean you don't need to corrupt people's data by changing `'` to back-ticks (although actually there is a way of escaping single quotes).

Parameterize

For example:

```
const string query = @"
if not exists(select id from user_detail where id_str = @idstr)
begin
    insert into user_detail(id_str,screen_name,user_name,createdate,hashtag,imageurl,message,unique_id,tweet_id)
    values(@idstr, @screenName, /*...*/)
end
else
begin
     update user_detail set screen_name= @screenName
     -- ...
end";
```

There are lots of ways of doing the actual execution.  For example with raw ADO.NET:

```
using(var cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) {
    cmd.CommandText = query;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("idstr", idstr);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("screenName", screenName);
    // ...
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

or with "dapper":

```
conn.Execute(query, new { idstr, screenName, /* ... */ });
```

In all cases, `...` denotes where I've omitted additional things for you to fill in (the however-many columns / parameters / etc that describe your data).

Comment: for that what we want to do